# How does a non initialized channel behave?

Tags: go, null, initialization, channel

I have a struct that holds a channel that is not initialized.

When I write into it, the routine is blocking as expected but the reader is never notified that something is in the pipe.

I am surprised that there is no error and I am wondering what is doing Go.

In the example bellow, neither the message `pushed` nor `got it` are printed. (Uncomment the intialization and it will work like a charm)

```
type MyStruct struct {
    over chan bool
}

func main() {
    nonInitialized := &MyStruct{}
    // nonInitialized.over = make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            select {
            case <-nonInitialized.over:
                fmt.Println("got it")
            default:
                // proceed
            }
            fmt.Println("do some stuff")
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        }
        panic("took too long")
    }()
    // push on the non initialized channel
    fmt.Println("pushing")
    nonInitialized.over <- true
    fmt.Println("pushed")
}
```

Here is the playground https://play.golang.org/p/76zrCuoeoh

(I know I should initialize the channel, this is not the purpose of the question, I want to know what is happening in Go with non initialized channels.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An "uninitialized" field or variable of [channel type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) will have the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of all channel types which is `nil`. So let's examine how a `nil` channel or operations on it behave.

**It is worth collecting the *channel axioms* in one post:**

- a send on a `nil` channel blocks forever ([Spec: Send statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements))
- a receive from a `nil` channel blocks forever ([Spec: Receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator))
- a send to a closed channel panics ([Spec: Send statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements))
- a receive from a closed channel returns the zero value immediately ([Spec: Receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator))

Reasoning for blocking in case of `nil` channels: if a channel value is `nil`, no one has a reference to it, so no one will ever be ready to receive from it (what we want to send); or send anything on it (what we would receive from it).

You can read further reasoning and more details about this in [Dave Cheney: Channel Axioms](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms).

**For completeness:**

- [Closing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) a `nil` channel causes a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics) (just like closing an already closed channel).
- [Length and capacity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity) of a `nil` channel is `0`; in accordance with `nil` slices and maps having `0` length and capacity.

Reasoning: "closed" is a state, but a `nil` channel cannot have a state (there is only one `nil` channel, and not one for "closed" and one for "not closed" channel). And there are no elements queued in a `nil` channel (so len = 0), and it does not have a buffer capacity (so cap = 0).

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior. A send to a `nil` channel blocks forever. You can read about it in the specs here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements

The same is also applicable for a recieve on a `nil` channel. (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)

You can also keep this link handy for reference: http://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms