# Stuck with Channels in golang

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I need to run a function multiple times in parallel.
If even once the functions returns `true` (sends `true` on the channel) then the final result should be `true`.

How do I achieve this using goroutines and channels?

```
// Some performance intensive function
func foo(i int, c chan bool) {
    // do some processing and return either true or false
    c <- true // or false
}

func main() {
    flg := false
    ch := make(chan bool)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go foo(i, ch)
    }
    // If even once foo() returned true then val should be true
    flg = flg || <-ch
}
```

Comment: "How do I achieve this using channels?" --- any reason you must use channels for it?

Comment: Please show us your attempt. Your code doesn't use channels at all.

Comment: (also, you'd be well advised to use `gofmt`, as your code is not easy to read as written)

Comment: @zerkms Channels are not necessary. Just that initially the call to foo() was sequential. Now I want to run them in parallel. I think only goroutine won't help since I need the return values as well. Any other idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question says you need help with channels. We're not here to write your code for you.  Please update your question to show your attempt, and explain your problems.

Comment: Please readup on channels and put the relevant code here before asking queries. Golang tour is one resource https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only receive one value from the channel (which will be the value sent by one of the `foo()` calls, unpredictable which of the many), but you want to receive all.

So use a `for` loop to receive as many values as you send (sent) on it:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    flg = flg || <-ch
}
```

Although in your case it would be enough to loop until one `true` value is received, as that will determine the final value of `flg`, but it is still recommended to receive all values else the remaining goroutines will be blocked (as `ch` is an unbuffered channel). In this example it does not matter, but in a "real-life" application it would cause goroutines to stuck forever (memory-leak).

If you don't want to wait for all `foo()` calls to complete and return as soon as possible (as soon as one `true` value is encountered), an option is to make `ch` buffered, so all goroutines can send values on it without getting blocked. And this way you are not required to receive (and thus wait for) all the `foo()` calls to complete:

```
ch := make(chan bool, 10)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    go foo(i, ch)
}

flg := false
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    if <-ch {
        flg = true
        break
    }
}
```

Choosing this approach, you should provide means to cancel goroutines whose work is no longer needed to avoid unnecessary CPU (and memory) usage. [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) is such a mean, read more about it here: [Close multiple goroutine if an error occurs in one in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500836/close-multiple-goroutine-if-an-error-occurs-in-one-in-go/45502591#45502591).

Answer (score 3):

You may start reading from the channel `ch` and set `flg` to `true` once you get true result. Like this:

```
//flg = flg || <- ch
for res := range ch {
    if res {
        flg = true
    }
}
```

This way works but has one serious drawback - `for` loop waits new values from channel infinitely. Idiomatic way to stop the loop is to close the channel. You may do it so: run a separate goroutine which will wait until all goroutines exit. Go provides a very convenient tools to do it - [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

Define it in a global scope so every goroutine can access to it:

```
var (
    wg sync.WaitGroup
)
```

Then every time you launch goroutine you add one more goroutine to wait group:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)   // here
    go foo(i, ch)
}
```

When goroutine finishes it calls `wg.Done` method to mark it.

```
func foo(i int, c chan bool) {
    //do some processing and return either true or false
    c <- true   //or false
    wg.Done()   // here
}
```

Then sepatate goroutine waits until all foo goroutines exit and closes the channel. `wg.Wait` blocks until all are done:

```
 go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}()
```

All together:  https://play.golang.org/p/8qiuA29-jv