# Panic while trying to stop creating more goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying to parallelize calls to an API to speed things up, but I'm facing a problem where I need to stop spinning up goroutines to call the API if I receive an error from one of the goroutine calls. Since I am closing the channel twice(once in the error handling part and when the execution is done), I'm getting a `panic: close of closed channel` error. Is there an elegant way to handle this without the program to panic? Any help would be appreciated!

The following is the pseudo-code snippet.

```
for i := 0; i < someNumber; i++ {
    go func(num int, q chan<- bool) {
        value, err := callAnAPI()
        if err != nil {
            close(q)//exit from the for-loop
        }
        // process the value here
        wg.Done()
    }(i, quit)
}
close(quit)
```

To mock my scenario, I have written the following program. Is there any way to exit the for-loop gracefully once the condition(commented out) is satisfied?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func receive(q <-chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-q:
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    quit := make(chan bool)

    var result []int
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(num int, q chan<- bool) {
            //if num == 5 {
            //  close(q)
            //}
            result = append(result, num)

            wg.Done()
        }(i, quit)
    }
    close(quit)
    receive(quit)

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("Result: %v", result)
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `close` in the gorotine?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. Are you trying to start goroutines until one of them fails, at which point you stop creating more but wait for the already running ones to finish?

Comment: I want the loop to end once it results in an error. To mimic that scenario, I added a `if num == 5` condition instead of `if err != nil`. To clarify my situation, let's say I have to call the API 100 times, I have set a max goroutines to 10, the API returns with an error on the 5th calls, I don't want the rest of the 90 calls to the API to be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package which defines the Context type, which carries deadlines, cancellation signals, and other request-scoped values across API boundaries and between processes.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel() // cancel when we are finished, even without error

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(num int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return // Error occured somewhere, terminate
            default: // avoid blocking
            }

            // your code here
            // res, err := callAnAPI()
            // if err != nil {
            //  cancel()
            //  return
            //}

            if num == 5 {
                cancel()
                return
            }

            fmt.Println(num)

        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
}
```

Try on: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/C8x6YomxlPB)

You can also take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45502591/11032044) for more detailed explanation.