# A channel is nil when it returned with a naked return

Tags: go

I've spent pretty significant amount of time trying to debug why my channel doesn't accept anything. I managed to localize the issue as the one related to the scope of named return values when they are returned with naked returns. The below code shows the problem.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

var receiver chan int

func Setup() (receiver chan int) {
    receiver = make(chan int)
    return
}

//func Setup() (chan int) {
//  receiver = make(chan int)
//  return receiver
//}

func Launch(j int){

    for i := 0; i < j; i++ {
        receiver <- i
    }

}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)

    rcvr := Setup()

    go func() {
        for r := range rcvr {
            log.Println(r)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()

    Launch(10)

    wg.Wait()

 }
```

Running this code produces the next error

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send (nil chan)]:

...
```

I cannot grasp why the channel should be nil. I tried similar assignment with primitive values and it returns what I expect. Why is it nil with channels? What shadows what in here?

Comment: you are creating a new channel not using the one you have assigned in `launch` function that's why the channel is nil.

Comment: I have update the code snippet. Please, pay attention to a channel name in main function. It is now changed to 'rcvr'. Main function and other code are supposed to be in different packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** to your edited code:

Now you are using 2 completely different channels. You have one channel in your `main()`, which you try to receive from (using a `for range`). And you have another channel (the global `receiver` variable to which you never assign any values, so it remains `nil`. And sending values on a `nil` channel blocks forever (see [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave/39016004#39016004) for details).

So there you have it: `Launch()` is blocked at sending on a `nil` channel, and your `main()` goroutine waits for the other goroutine it launched, which waits for values on the `rcvr` channel to which no one sends anything.

An easy way would be to pass the channel to `Launch()` you create in `main()`, and get rid of the global var:

```
func Launch(j int, receiver chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < j; i++ {
        receiver <- i
    }
}
```

And when calling it:

```
Launch(10, rcvr)
```

Then it will work, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oaqjXuG4QAi)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 0
2009/11/10 23:00:00 1
2009/11/10 23:00:00 2
2009/11/10 23:00:00 3
2009/11/10 23:00:00 4
2009/11/10 23:00:00 5
2009/11/10 23:00:00 6
2009/11/10 23:00:00 7
2009/11/10 23:00:00 8
2009/11/10 23:00:00 9
```

---

Original answer follows:

The problem is that you use [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) in your main when storing the channel returned by `Setup()`:

```
receiver := Setup()
```

This will **not** assign a value to your global `receiver` variable, but create a new local variable which shadows the global variable, and your `main()` function will use this local variable. But your `Launch()` function will use the global variable (it doesn't see `main`'s local variables).

Use simple [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments), and all will be good:

```
receiver = Setup()
```

Comment: My mistake in wrong naming of the variable in main. I should have named it different. For example rcvr = Setup(). The issue still remains. If I switch Setup functions with one I had commented out, everything works all right.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. Please, take a look.

Comment: @AndreiPiakhota Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. But I don't get it. And the place I don't get it is my Setup function that uses a named return value. In this function I have this initialization `receiver = make(chan int)`. What does it initialize? I thought it was my global `receiver` variable, reference to which I then return to main function. From you answer I infer that my global variable has been shadowed by a local variable which I named the same. Therefore my global `receiver` variable has never been touched. Is this the case?

Comment: @AndreiPiakhota Yes, exactly. Your named result variable shadows the global, so you never touch the global variable.

Comment: Now I get it. Shadowing is something to take a closer look into. Thanks a lot. The question may be considered as answered.

Comment: @AndreiPiakhota Then you should consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.