# Golang channel in struct behaves differently by passing it when creating the struct and passing by function after creating

Tags: go, struct, channel

To illustrate the problem, I wrote some demo codes. See the runnable code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type structOfChan struct {
    Name     string
    signalCh chan bool
}

func (sc structOfChan) Init() {
    sc.signalCh = make(chan bool, 1)
}

func (sc structOfChan) Notify() {
    sc.signalCh <- true
    fmt.Println(sc.Name, "notified")
}
func main() {
    sc1 := structOfChan{
        Name:     "created with Channel",
        signalCh: make(chan bool, 1),
    }

    sc2 := structOfChan{Name: "created without channel"}
    sc2.Init()
    go func() {
        sc1.Notify()
    }()
    go func() {
        sc2.Notify()
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

}
```

The output of above code is `created with Channel notified`.

That means when you create a struct without `signalCh` and then pass it to the struct by `init`, `signalCh` will block when some value passed to it.

How did this happen? why does the two approach of passing channels make the difference?

Comment: You must use pointer receiver for methods that intend to change the receiver (because the receiver is just a copy). When you change it to pointer, it works, see on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iLlPpes8jEa). If you use a non-pointer receiver, the `signalCh` field of the "original" struct remains `nil`, and attempting to send on a `nil` channel blocks forever. For details, see [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave/39016004#39016004)

Answer (score 0):

https://play.golang.org/p/TIn7esSsRUZ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type structOfChan struct {
    Name     string
    signalCh chan bool
}

func (sc *structOfChan) Init() {
    sc.signalCh = make(chan bool, 1)
}

func (sc *structOfChan) Notify() {
    sc.signalCh <- true
    fmt.Println(sc.Name, "notified")
}
func main() {
    sc1 := &structOfChan{
        Name:     "created with Channel",
        signalCh: make(chan bool, 1),
    }

    sc2 := &structOfChan{Name: "created without channel"}
    sc2.Init()
    go func() {
        sc1.Notify()
    }()
    go func() {
        sc2.Notify()
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

}
```

output:

`created with Channel notified
created without channel notified`

To be able to modify struct fields, you need to make reciever functions on pointer values