# Why does my `for-select` statement keeps receiving from my channel even after I close it?

Tags: for-loop, go, channel

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)
    go func(c chan int, c2 chan int) {
        for {
            select {
            case v := <-c:
                fmt.Println(v)
            case v := <-c2:
                fmt.Println(v)
            default:
            }
        }
    }(ch, ch2)
    ch <- 1
    close(ch)
    close(ch2)
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

When I run this, it prints `1` to the stdout, and then keeps printing `0`. Why is this?

I know I can check whether the channel is closed in my goroutine, but I just want to know the reason for this.

Also, suppose I want to exit from a goroutine after all(multiple) channels are closed, is that possible?  I was assuming that once all channels are closed, I could potentially exit from the goroutine in the default case after all channels are closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the expected behavior per [Spec: Receive operator:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)

> A receive operation on a [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) after any previously sent values have been received.

See [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave/39016004#39016004)

If you want to terminate a loop once all values have been received from a channel (that were sent on it before it was closed), use the `for ... range` construct, for example:

```
c := make(chan int) // Initialize some channel

for v := range c {
    fmt.Println("Received:", v)
}
```

If you have multiple channels and you want to receive from all, you may use multiple goroutines, each having a `for range` for a designated channel.

Another solution is:

> A function can read from multiple inputs and proceed until all are closed by multiplexing the input channels onto a single channel that's closed when all the inputs are closed. This is called fan-in.

Read more about it in [The Go Blog
Go Concurrency Patterns: Pipelines and cancellation: Fan-out- fain-in](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines).

Comment: so suppose I want to exit from a goroutine after all channels are closed, is that possible?  I was assuming that once all channels are closed, I could potentially exit from the goroutine in the default case after all channels are closed

Comment: @AyushGupta Simply use `for ... range`, which terminates once all values are received and the channel is closed.

Comment: But that translates into multiple goroutines each with its own `for...range` loops if I want to receive from multiple channels concurrently

Comment: This blog post is very instructive on the topic of selects on closed channels & how to leverage nil channels: https://medium.com/justforfunc/why-are-there-nil-channels-in-go-9877cc0b2308

Comment: @colminator thanks for the link! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3):

> [The Go Programming Language Specificatio](https://golang.org/ref/spec)n
>
> [Close](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close)
>
> After calling close, and after any previously sent values have been
>   received, receive operations will return the zero value for the
>   channel's type without blocking.
>
> [Receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)
>
> A receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed
>   immediately, yielding the element type's zero value after any
>   previously sent values have been received.