# Why does reading from a nil channel increase the number of Goroutines?

Tags: go, memory-leaks, channel, goroutine

I'm reading this blog, https://medium.com/golangspec/goroutine-leak-400063aef468, and have adapted the following example illustrating a goroutine leak due to receiving from a nil channel:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

var initChannel bool

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    var ch chan int
    if initChannel {
        ch = make(chan int, 1)
        ch <- 1
    }
    go func(ch chan int) {
        <-ch
    }(ch)

    c := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
    for range c {
        fmt.Printf("#goroutines: %d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }
}

func init() {
    flag.BoolVar(&initChannel, "init", false, "initialize channel")
}
```

I've noticed that if I run it with `initChannel` `false`, the number of goroutines is 2:

```
> go run main.go
#goroutines: 2
#goroutines: 2
```

whereas if I run it with `true`, the number is 1:

```
> go run main.go --init
#goroutines: 1
#goroutines: 1
```

I don't quite understand why this is the case, however. I only see one `go` statement, so I would expect only one goroutine in either case. Why are there two goroutines when reading from a nil channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your app starts, there is already one goroutine that runs the `main()` function.

If you don't initialize the `ch` channel, it will remain its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) which is `nil` for channels. [Spec: Receive operator:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)

> Receiving from a `nil` channel blocks forever.

For details, see [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave/39016004#39016004)

So if the channel is `nil`, the launched goroutine will never end. So you will have 2 goroutines: the `main` goroutine and the one you launched.

If you initialize the channel with 1 buffer and send one value on it, then you will also have 2 goroutines for a "short period of time", but the launched goroutine can receive a value from it and then end immediately. So there will be a single goroutine remaining, the `main` goroutine.