# Conditional Timeout

Tags: go, timer, channel

I have some code, there are 3 timers,

- GracefulExecutionTimeout - total running time
- WaitTimeout - time to initial wait for first message
- IdleTimeout - time to wait for subsequent messages

If any of the timers are reached the app should cleanly exit. I have it working below

```
msgs := make(chan string)

go func() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    msgs <- "test"
}()
// graceful max execution time
gracefulMaxTimeout := time.Second * time.Duration(10)
gracefulMaxTimer := time.NewTimer(gracefulMaxTimeout)

// idleTimeout
idleTimeout := time.Second * time.Duration(5)
idleTimer := time.NewTimer(idleTimeout)

// waitTimeout
waitTimeout := time.Second * time.Duration(2)
waitTimer := time.NewTimer(waitTimeout)
for {
    select {
    case <-gracefulMaxTimer.C:
        fmt.Println("GracefulMaxExecutionTimeout Reached")

        // graceful exit
        os.Exit(0)
    case <-idleTimer.C:
        fmt.Println("IdleTimeout Reached")

        // graceful exit
        os.Exit(0)
    case <-waitTimer.C:
        fmt.Println("WaitTimeout Reached")
        // graceful exit
        os.Exit(0)
    case msg := <-msgs:
        // stop wait timer
        waitTimer.Stop()
        fmt.Println(msg)

        // Reset idle timer
        if !idleTimer.Stop() {
            <-idleTimer.C
        }
        fmt.Println("IdleIimeout Reset")
        idleTimer.Reset(idleTimeout)
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6alBK0pbRxx)

I want to make the WaitTimeout optional but not sure how to approach it. If i surround the construction of the `waitTimer` with an `if` statement then it wont work as the `waitTimer` isnt defined for the `select` statement ... How can i make the WaitTimeout conditional ?

I can just `.Stop()` the timer after its created but that seems a little dirty ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may declare the wait timer and its channel outside the `if` statement, and only initialize them if wait timer is needed. If not, the channel may remain its zero value–which is `nil`–because receiving from a `nil` channel blocks forever, so this `case` will never be ready (for details, see [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave/39016004#39016004)).

```
useWaitTimer := true

var (
    waitTimer  *time.Timer
    waitTimerC <-chan time.Time
)
if useWaitTimer {
    waitTimeout := time.Millisecond * time.Duration(500)
    waitTimer = time.NewTimer(waitTimeout)
    waitTimerC = waitTimer.C
}

// ...

for {
    select {
    // ...

    case <-waitTimerC:
        fmt.Println("WaitTimeout Reached")
        // graceful exit
        os.Exit(0)

    // ...
    }
}
```

Then of course you can only reset the wait timer if it exists, this must also be checked (and don't forget to drain the channel if it returns `false`):

```
// stop wait timer if exists
if waitTimer != nil && !waitTimer.Stop() {
    <-waitTimerC
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5l-KJWEYO13).

Comment: Can please explain why you did `waitTimer  *time.Timer` not `waitTimer  time.Timer` ? new to Go

Comment: Because `time.NewTimer()` returns a value of type `*time.Timer`, a pointer, and not `time.Timer`.

Comment: OK - so the types match. Thanks